# C# distinguish Drag drop and Mouse click

Tags: c#, events, triggers, cursor

I have a form which allows drop and also I need to capture the click event.

The tricky part here, is when the user drags and drop the object on the form, the `MouseClickEvent` also fired-because he also clicked the mouse to release the drop.

How may I handle each on of this events in a separate event trigger?

Thanks in advance!

This is a short and more logic question so i didn't see a real reason to put pieces of code here..

Thanks!

Comment: A global (boolean) variable delivers an easy and reliable solution for these situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a global boolean, for instance:

```
private bool isDragAndDrop;
```

Set it to false when loading the form. When the dragAndDrop event is fired you should set `isDragAndDrop = true`.

When the Click event is fired you check `if(!isDragAndDrop)` This will or will not execute the code inside the click event based on the value on the isDragAndDrop -variable.

Before leaving the click event you the set `isDragAndDrop = false`

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on this [link](http://code.rawlinson.us/2007/04/c-dragdrop-and-doubleclick.html)

```
    private void MyMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Clicks == 1)
        {
            Control source = (Control)sender;
            source.DoDragDrop(new MyWrapper(source), DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
```

by Bill Rawlinson — 18 Apr 2007

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer could considered late.

But I have this issue recently and I tried most of the answer from stackoverflow but still no luck.

Finally I solved the issue with code below.

Hope it can provide some help.

```
public int clickCnt = 0;

void btn_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        clickCnt++;
        if (clickCnt > 5)
        {
            DoDragDrop(btn, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}

void btn_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    clickCnt = 0;
}

void btn_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print("btnConn_MouseClick");
    //Do click thing
}

//this should replace the component that you want process dragdrop event.
void tabControl1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    clickCnt = 0;
    //Do drop thing
}
```